# Used gem install rails and now I have 4.0.0.rc1 - I want Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

How can I switch back?

I installed RVM, then installed Ruby 1.9.3, then ran `gem install rails`.

Running `rails -v` I can see that I have `Rails 4.0.0.rc1` and I don't want to use that version as it's not supported on my hosting provider.

How can I install Rails 3.2.13 and have that be used as default when running `rails new` commands?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
gem uninstall rails

gem install rails --version "=3.2.13"
```

Answer (score 11):

Try: `gem install rails --version 3.2.13 --no-ri --no-rdoc`

(`--no-ri --no-rdoc`) is optional to speed up the process and skip rdoc generation etc.

Comment: 1 up for pointing out options `--no-ri --no-rdoc`, they speed up the process by a considerable factor.

Answer (score 2):

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.13 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```